# Python Script to find IP address with more than 30 attacks

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to create a Python script that allows me to search through an `auth.log` file and search for IP Address with more than 30 failed attempts then create a blacklist file where those IP Address would then be saved. This is what I have so far but the regular expression doesn't seem to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re # allows me to use regular expressions 

#attempts = 0 #setting the variable 'attempts' to 0
myAuthlog=open('auth.log', 'r') #open the auth.log for reading

#open the Security_Test.txt for writing later
myTxtFile = open('blacklistips.txt','w')

#write to the file what we are analysing
myTxtFile.write('The security options for httpd.conf\n')

for line in myAuthlog: #go through each line of the file and return it to the variable line
    if re.match("([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$'", line): #if the regular expressions matches 'bin' or 'Bin' in line
```

An example from the log file is:

```
Feb  5 08:34:51 j4-be02 sshd[2281]: Failed password for root from 5.199.133.223 port 42582 ssh2
Feb  5 08:34:56 j4-be02 sshd[2283]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=5.199.133.223  user=root
Feb  5 08:34:58 j4-be02 sshd[2283]: Failed password for root from 5.199.133.223 port 50099 ssh2
Feb  5 08:35:04 j4-be02 sshd[2285]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=5.199.133.223  user=root
```

i need to search through this file and find all the IP Addresses and `authentication failure` and if there are more than 30 failures those IP Address get written to a text file.

Comment: The title of your question is far too broad to be answerable and your question isn't a question - it's a script and a statement saying it doesn't work. Tell us the problem you're trying to solve, the problem you're having, what you've tried to do to solve it, and some sample input and output.

Comment: Can you show structure of `auth.log` and tell us what's the regular expression supposed to do?

Comment: Updated above, i need to search through this file and find all the IP Addresses and 'authentication failure' and if there are more than 30 failures those IP Address get written to a text file

Answer (score 0):

you have to store your matched IP into a collection and then once you are done with iterating all lines process collection and see count of every unique IP, if it  is more than 30 write value into a file. The collection used could be dictonary.

Answer (score 0):

The following kind of approach should work fine. It makes use of Python's [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#counter-objects) to total up all of the matching IP addresses. Then it writes any which have been seen more than 30 times to a black list file:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

with open('auth.log') as f_authlog:
    authlog = f_authlog.read()
    ip_addresses = Counter(re.findall(r'authentication failure.*?rhost=([0-9.]*)\s', authlog))

with open('blacklist.txt', 'w') as f_blocked:
    for ip_address, count in ip_addresses.iteritems():
        if count > 30:
            f_blocked.write('{}\n'.format(ip_address))
```